# Play videos with buffering in my server

Tags: plugins, video-player

I want to play videos on my WordPress page. But my videos are on my server. How can I offer to viewers play the videos with buffering like youtube (if you internet its low you can see it in 720p or lower)?
Is it difficult? exist a plugin for this? (I google it before, but I can not find a plugin for this)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about how much control you want to offer to your viewers but you can always use the `<video>` tag in HTML to display a player. You can read more about this here - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

If you are looking to provide the option of adjusting the quality and all you might have to host it on YouTube or some similar platform.

Hosting on such platforms also has its own advantages like you don't have to worry about bandwidth and storage space.